# Complemented with or complemented by

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, phrasal-verbs, expression-choice, by-with

I read the sentence

> The food was complemented with an array of musical bands.

My question has two parts:

1. Can food be complemented with music?
2. The difference between *complemented by* and *complemented with*. Are both correct? If not what is the difference?

Comment: array of musical bands? That would get pretty noisy...would you even enjoy  your food?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a passive construction. "Moscato wine complements chocolate" = "Chocolate is complemented by Moscato wine". However, I feel that in the context of your example, there's no intention to convey that the music was chosen to complement the food; the music merely *accompanies* it.

Answer (score 4):

Both prepositions are about equally common in OP's context, and I see no reason to prefer one over the other (nor do I see any possible *semantic* distinction). From Google Books...

> *His report [was complemented **with** information](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was%20complemented%20with%20information%22) from (some reliable source).* (456 hits)
>    *His report [was complemented **by** information](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was%20complemented%20by%20information%22) from that analysis.* (519 hits)

But as has been pointed out, most people probably wouldn't use the passive construction for OP's *Can food be complemented with/by music?* They'd more likely ask *Can music complement food?*

Comment: An answer actually showing reasonable research. (This comment not really @FF, of course.)

Comment: I conjecture that if one asked each person whose utterance is included in those samples whether they meant "supplemented", a substantial portion of them would think it over and say "yes".

Answer (score 1):

The idea underlying 'complemented' is completion. OOD gives this definition of the verb to complement: "Contribute extra features to (someone or something) in such a way as to improve or emphasize their qualities."

The writer of the sentence you quote believes that the music improved the experience of enjoying the food.

I don't see any difference between with and by in the context of your sentence.